# How to make `integrate()` to accept a vector in an R function?

Tags: r, function, vectorization, integral, numerical-integration

I am wondering how I could make my function `Bpp` to ***accept a vector for its first argument*** `t`?

```
Bpp = function(t, n1, n2 = NULL){

      N = ifelse(is.null(n2), n1, n1*n2/(n1+n2))
     df = ifelse(is.null(n2), n1 - 1, n1 + n2 - 2)

     H1 = integrate(function(delta)dcauchy(delta, 0, sqrt(2)/2)*dt(t, df, delta*sqrt(N)), -Inf, Inf)[[1]]
     H0 = dt(t, df)
   BF10 = H1/H0
p.value = 2*(1-pt(abs(t), df))

list(BF10 = BF10, p.value = p.value)
}

Bpp(t = -6:6, 20, 20) ## This will give error because `t` is now a vector?
```

Comment: `Vectorize` is typically useful in these situations. Although rewriting it to directly accept a vector is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I could give a quick answer without testing. Use the following in your `Bpp`:

```
# joint density
joint <- function(delta, t) dcauchy(delta, 0, sqrt(2)/2) * dt(t, df, delta*sqrt(N))
# marginal density of `t`
marginal.t <- function (t) integrate(joint, lower = -Inf, upper = Inf, t = t)[[1]]
H1 <- sapply(t, marginal.t)
```

> So, here we also could use `Vectorize` how would that look like?

Use your original `Bpp`:

```
Bpp <- Vectorize(Bpp, vectorize.args = "t")
Bpp(-6:6, 20, 20)
```